# Tab Bars, View Controllers, and Story Boards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

OK, so I have a slight conundrum to solve.

I have a tab bar controller where two tabs (in reality it's three but this shows the problem) have essentially the same UI.

They show the information in the same way but they use different queries to get that information.

Now, because they are separate tabs I need to have two instances on the Storyboard in order to create those tabs. Each tab also has a UINavigationController for the "root" of the tab. But this means that any UI I set up in one has to be duplicated in the other one. I use run time attributes to change where the controller gets the info from.

I could just have one instance and connect it to both navigation controllers. This means I can make the UI changes in just one place but then how can I configure each view controller to get the correct info?

I'm sure there is a way around this but I'm stuck in my head and can't find a way out at the moment.

If anyone can understand what I'm talking about could you please offer any advice you have.

This is what I've tried based on the answer but it only loads on the first tab. The subsequent tabs just have a nag controller without a root view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the navigation controller (with its top view controller) for a second time to the tab bar controller by control-dragging again from the tab bar controller, and choosing "view controllers". This will give you two instances of the navigation controller and two of its top view controller. This way, you only have one scene that you have to edit if you change the UI. I tested this by starting with the tabbed application template, embedding the second controller in a navigation controller, and then control-dragging to that second navigation controller to connect it up the second time. You will only see the one title in tab bar item in the navigation controller, so I did the following in the SecondViewController.m to change the title,

```
@interface SecondViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@end

@implementation SecondViewController {
    BOOL isThird;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    if ([self.navigationController isEqual:self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2]]) isThird = YES;
    if (isThird) {
        self.navigationController.tabBarItem.title = @"Third";
    }
}


-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (isThird) {
        self.label.text = @"Third View";
    }else{
        self.label.text = @"Second View";
    }
}
```

This will give you a new title for that third controller, and you can use the BOOL, isThird, in your code to distinguish between the two instance of SecondViewController when you want to load different information into them.

[image]

Comment: AMAZING! That's really excellent thanks! I was trying to find a way to access the "rootViewController" segue and work something out from there. I hadn't thought about using the title of the NavigationController. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hmm... this doesn't seem to work. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Fogmeister, I haven't tried the setup that you show in your edit, and that's not what I did. I had two connections from the tab bar controller to the same navigation controller scene. I've edited my answer to include a screenshot of my storyboard.

Comment: Ah, that's probably a better way of doing it :)